# More Simple Password System Stuff

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

Sorry guys, first time playing around with this. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SuM BUTtonsS DOe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Please enter the password</p>
    <form id="enter" onSubmit="javascript:passCheck()">
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </form>
    <p id="incorrect"><em>INCORRECT PASSWORD</em></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function passCheck() {
            var input = document.getElementById('password').value;

            if (input == 'herro') {
                window.alert("IT WORKS!!");
            }
            else {
                var incorrect = document.getElementById('incorrect');
                incorrect.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I enter the wrong password, INCORRECT PASSWORD comes up, but only for a fraction of a second. Then it's gone again. No idea why.

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SuM BUTtonsS DOe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Please enter the password</p>
    <form id="enter" onSubmit="javascript:passCheck()">
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </form>
    <p id="incorrect"><em>INCORRECT PASSWORD</em></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function passCheck() {
            var input = document.getElementById('password').value;

            if (input == 'herro') {
                window.alert("IT WORKS!!");
            }
            else {
                var incorrect = document.getElementById('incorrect');
                incorrect.style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but client (browser) side password validation isn't going to fly - you'll need to post the password (with HTTPS) up to the server to make that decision.

Comment: Could you post a codepen or a jsfiddle?

Comment: StuartLC yes, I know, it's just a basic little practice thing. But thanks!

Comment: I just tried making a JS Fiddle, but it didn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

On submit, the form will trigger the default action, which in this case is to submit the contents to the same page (for lack of an `action` property).

So what you're seeing is the JavaScript runs and changes the style to show the error message, then the page reloads.

To ensure the page doesn't reload put `return false` at the end of `passCheck`. Better would be to use `addEventListener` and `event.preventDefault()`, but that's a little bit more involved.

Comment: Didn't work. I updated the question with the code - is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Please enter the password</p>
<form id="enter" onSubmit="passCheck(); return false;">
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<p id="incorrect" style="display: none"><em>INCORRECT PASSWORD</em></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function passCheck() {
        var input = document.getElementById('password').value;

        if (input == 'herro') {
            window.alert("IT WORKS!!");
        }
        else {
            var incorrect = document.getElementById('incorrect');
            incorrect.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to bind the validation to the `click` event of a button. You can submit the form by pressing `enter` while focus is on the password field, in that case nothing would happen. It's more correct to put the validation on the submit event.